# How to map the touch x, y to my canvas

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, android-canvas

I have a task to build image editor and to be able to draw on my image

attached is my example

[image]

the problem now that when I try to draw the drawing line is shifted, and also when I try to draw outside of my image, it draw also, so how can I solve this problem

my code is as following :

```
float touchX = event.getX();
float touchY = event.getY();
Log.i("AMIRA" , "X: " + touchX + " Y: " +touchY);
//respond to down, move and up events
switch (event.getAction()) {
     case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
         drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
         break;
     case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

         canvasBitmap = ((FastBitmapDrawable) getDrawable()).getBitmap();
         mutableBitmap = canvasBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
         drawCanvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);

         float x1= touchX - drawCanvas.getClipBounds().left;
         float y1= touchY - drawCanvas.getClipBounds().top;

         //drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
         drawPath.lineTo(x1, y1);
         drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
         setImageBitmap(mutableBitmap);
         break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

         canvasBitmap = ((FastBitmapDrawable) getDrawable()).getBitmap();
         mutableBitmap = canvasBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
         drawCanvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);

         float x2= touchX - drawCanvas.getClipBounds().left;
         float y2= touchY - drawCanvas.getClipBounds().top;

         //drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
         drawPath.lineTo(x2, y2);
         drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
         drawPath.reset();
         setImageBitmap(mutableBitmap);
         break;
    default:
         return false;
 }
 invalidate();
 return true;
```